# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } when using iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have been trying to use an iFrame to load web pages from an external site. The links to the pages are being dynamically loaded from a web server.

Without the iFrames, the website loads up perfectly, however when I add in the iFrame I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

The Log says it is on line 2 of the HTML file which is: `<head>`

I'm not really sure what's wrong or what to do. Can anybody help me resolve this please?

The iFrame's code looks like: `<iframe id="aModule" src="#error"></iframe>`

The src is changed using this function (which is never used because the `alert()` lines are never triggered:

```
function setTheModule(link){
alert();
    document.getElementById("aModule").src = link;
    alert();
}
```

`setTheModule` is called from another list which is dynamically generated using these methods:

```
function loadModules(course){
var data = {
  "fn" : "mod",
  "data": course,
  "ajax" : "true"
};
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: SERVICE_URL, //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
  data: data,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(response) {

    var i, list = "";
        for (i = 0; i < response.module.length; i++) {
            list += formatModuleListItem(response.module[i]);
        }
        window.location="#modules";
        $("#mList").html(list).listview('refresh');
  }
});

}

function formatModuleListItem(item){
var fItem = "<li class='wrap'><a href='#' onclick='setTheModule('http://" + item.link +"')'>"+ item.name +"</p></li>";
return fItem;
}
```

I really hope somebody can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have a syntax error in your `formatModuleListItem` function, You have to change it to something like this:

```
function formatModuleListItem(item){
var fItem = "<li class='wrap'><a href='#' onclick='setTheModule(\"http://" + item.link +"\")'>"+ item.name +"</a></li>";
return fItem;
}
```

you have this function `setTheModule('someVar')` and then you are encapsulating it in a string which will be something like this:

`onclick='setTheModule('someVar')'`

And there will be conflict between single quotes

So I have changed the function to `setTheModule(\"someVar\")`

And then also there was no `<p>` so I removed `</p>` from the end of the string and added a `</a>`.

Hope Changing it solves your problem